# Cant edit animation once created in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Im having a very weird/frustrating problem, cant find anyone who's found a solution but I know I'm not the only one. After creating animations in unity, I'm unable to edit/change them. Only create new ones.

I have created an animation and attached the animation to a game object. The game object also has an animator attached, but I don't use it for running the animation. I run it by code.

I have tried clicking the game object and opening the animation window, double clicking the animation, opening animation, everything but all I get is:

[image]

I cant go back to one animation. How can I do this?

My inspector looks like

[image]

Comment: why not just using animator?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I am using animator thats what i said

Comment: You are using animator and animation together, I mean delete the attached animation and manage everything in the animator

Comment: That doesn't help me i need to edit the animation itself

Comment: You will be able to edit the animation when you do it through the animator panel. please read the animator manual